# Rails Model/Join table doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to join two pre-existing tables, "Report" and "Person", via the creation of a new join table "LastViewer". Basically, the Viewer table will track which person last viewed a report.

I created a Rails Model by creating a file "last_viewer.rb" like this:

```
class LastViewer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  belongs_to :person
end
```

This generated the following migration:

```
class CreateLastViewers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :last_viewers do |t|
      t.references :person
      t.references :report

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :last_viewers, :person_id
    add_index :last_viewers, :report_id
  end
end
```

Now, I started adding code so that my app would track changes. I added the following to the correct controller:

```
@viewer = LastViewer.new
@viewer.person_id = get_current_user[:id] # correctly gets the person's ID from the correct session
@viewer.report_id = @report.id
@viewer.save
```

And now, to the view I wanted to display the last viewer, I added:

```
<% @reports.each_with_index do |report,index| %>
  <% query = LastViewer.where(:report_id => report.id).last %>
  <% name = query.person.name || "No Person found" %>
  <% time = Format.to_time(query.created_at.localtime) %>
<% end %>
```

The error I get is:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

on the line

```
  <% name = query.person.name || "No Person found" %
```

Edit:

The respective part of the Person model:

```
class Person< ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hid, :name, :email, :cell, :display
  has_many :last_viewer
end
```

The respective part of the Report model:

```
class Report< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :last_viewer
end
```

Comment: Does get_current_user[:id] return anything? Did you define the has_many :through associations on your joined models?

Comment: Ensure that your model is requiring both foreign keys to successfully save: `validates :report_id, :person_id, presence: true` in your LastViewer model

Comment: Yes, get_current_user[:id] returns the correct string/name (I tested it). And I'm sorry, what do you mean by the second part? I will add the Report and Person models if that will help

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I did that but still the same problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change your relations to this: (plural on `has_many :last_viewers`)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :last_viewers


class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :last_viewers

class LastViewer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  belongs_to :person
  validates :report_id, :person_id, presence: true
```

Then, try to force the creation of the LastViewer object, to raise an error and see what's wrong with your object:

```
@viewer = LastViewer.new
@viewer.person_id = get_current_user[:id]
@viewer.report_id = @report.id
@viewer.save! # adding a ! will raise errors if object not valid

# one-line equivalent:
@viewer = LastViewer.create!(person_id: get_current_user[:id], report_id: @report.id)
```

I'm pretty sure it will an error like "person_id is not supposed to be blank". I think your method `get_current_user[:id]` does not return the id.

After you fixed this problem, I recommend you to refactor your view to:

```
<% @reports.each_with_index do |report, index| %>
  <% last_viewer = report.last_viewers.last %>
  <% last_person_name = last_viewer.try(:person).try(:name) %>
  <% time = Format.to_time(query.created_at.localtime) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You were correct about the get_current_user[:id], that returned the person's hid instead of id. It works now when I search on the Person table for where hid = get_current_user[:id] and then grab the id of the resulting user. Thank you so much, your input cracked the case! :)

Answer (score 2):

`query.person` is nil. You can use `try` to prevent the error:

```
<% name = query.person.try(:name) || "No Person found" %>
```

Comment: That fixed the error but now it simply prints "No Person found" (like it's supposed to, obviously). Do you see any other potential error? This is my first time joining tables so I'm not confident I did that correctly

Comment: Like others are suggesting, `get_current_user[:id]` is most likely not returning the id you think it should return. It should be returning the primary key (`id`) from the `Person` object.

Comment: I'm sorry, but by the primary key id you mean the id of the index of that Person in the Person table, correct?

Comment: Yes, the `id` column in the `Person` table.

Comment: OH. Ok, I see my mistake. There is actually another column in the Person table titled "hid", which is what get_current_user[:id] displays. It works now when I search on the Person table for where hid = get_current_user[:id] and then grab the id of the resulting user. Thank you so much!